# Which books would you recommend about Recreational Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, reference-request, recreational-mathematics

By this I mean books  with math puzzles and problems similar to the ones you would find in mathematical olympiads.

Comment: as opposed to Martin-Gardner-type essays?

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: Questions that are asking the user to create a list/collection of answers should be marked community wiki. I converted this question.

Comment: Olympiads are recreational to you?  Dang.

Comment: everyone may play what what (s)he likes :-)

Comment: in my opinion, olympiad problems are far from recreational ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're after Olympiad-level books, get [The IMO Compendium](http://books.google.com/books?id=rVvr2p76cKQC&printsec=frontcover) which is a collection of problems from the International Math Olympiad, 1959-2004. You can find similar books with national Olympiad problems by going to Amazon and searching for "mathematical Olympiad".

Two books that offer collections of techniques useful for olympiad-level contests are Paul Zeitz's [The Art and Craft of Problem Solving](http://books.google.com/books?id=Go_iAAAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover) and Arthur Engel's [Problem Solving Strategies](http://books.google.com/books?id=B3EYPeKViAwC&printsec=frontcover).

There are lots of other books with similar titles and descriptions. Just follow Google Books's suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Art of Problem Solving: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/index.php

Anything by Martin Gardner.

Comment: The Art of Problem Solving is very good for someone preparing for mathematics contests such as the AMC-12, but in my opinion too elementary for Olympiad-level training.

Answer (score 3):

THE PENGUIN DICTIONARY OF CURIOUS AND INTERESTING NUMBERS, by David Wells.

Sample entry:
$199: 199 + 210n$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ provides the smallest $8, 9$ and $10$ primes in arithmetical progression.

Obviously you can reformulate any of the information given in the book as a problem to pose to someone else.